# Inserting Links in GROUP_CONCAT Display

Tags: php, mysql

I recently learned how to use the GROUP_CONCAT command to display results that look like this:

gyrfalcon | Iceland, Mongolia
meadowlark | South Dakota, Wyoming

Now I'd like to know if there's a way to link the results (the place names), like this:

```
meadowlark | <a href="/world/south-dakota" title="South Dakota">South Dakota</a>, <a href="/world/wyoming" title="Wyoming">Wyoming</a>
```

In this particular example, the place names are stored in GG.Name, and the URL's are stored in GG.URL. Here's my query:

```
SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.GroupTax, PLAN.Desig, PLAN.Family,   PLAN.Order1, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GG.URL AS GURL, GG.Name AS Name, GROUP_CONCAT(GG.Name ORDER     BY GG.Name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS Names, GG.IDParent
FROM gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea
WHERE PLAN.Desig = :RefCat AND Rank != '55'
GROUP BY PLAN.Common
ORDER BY PLAN.N, GG.Name
```

And here's the rest of the script:

```
$PlaceGroup = $row['Names'];

echo '<tr>
  <td class="Symbol">&gt; <a href="'.$GZ_URL.'/life/'.$LatinL.'" title="'.$Symbol.'  ('.$Latin2.')">'.$row['Common'].'</a> (<em>'.$Latin2.'</em>)</td>
  <td class="Place">'.$PlaceGroup.'</td>
</tr>';
```

P.S. If I can't insert values from GG.URL, another possibility might be to simply modify the values from GG.Name. For example, if GG.Name = 'New York', then it could be converted to a link by simply changing it to lower case and replacing the space with a dash.

**EDIT: Here's my entire revised query, which displays a syntax error:**

```
SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.GroupTax, PLAN.Desig, PLAN.Family, PLAN.Order1, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GG.URL AS GURL, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href="', GG.URL, '" title="', GG.Name, '">', GG.Name, '</a>')) as Names, GG.Name, '</a>')) as LISTOFLINKS, GG.IDParent
FROM gs_planimals PLAN
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.Latin = PLAN.Latin
LEFT JOIN gw_geog GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea
WHERE PLAN.Desig = :RefCat AND Rank != '55'
GROUP BY PLAN.Common
ORDER BY PLAN.N, GG.Name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group concat the urls like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  CONCAT('<a href=\"', GG.URL, '\" title=\"', GG.Name, '\">', GG.Name, '</a>')
  ORDER BY GG.Name ASC SEPARATOR ', '
) as LISTOFLINKS
```

So on a single line you `CONCAT` fields to build the link and then `GROUP_CONCAT` the links into a single string of links.

(I escaped the double quotes in the string, although it seems to depend on the configuration whether that is needed).

Comment: You mean insert your code in the query, like this?: SELECT PLAN.Latin Latin2, PLAN.Common, PLAN.Rank, PLAN.GroupTax, PLAN.Desig, PLAN.Family, PLAN.Order1, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GG.URL AS GURL, GG.Name AS Name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href="', GG.URL, '" title="', GG.Name, '">', GG.Name, '</a>')) AS Names, GG.IDParent

I'm getting a syntax error. I thought I might have accidentally deleted a quote, but I don't see the problem.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', GG.URL, '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: Note: I edited my original post, added my revised query (the one producing the syntax error). I was a little confused by your statement "on a single line," so maybe I did something wrong there.

Comment: Oh, I guess I'm more confused than I thought. That's not the query I've been using at all. Do I need to create a second query just for GROUP_CONCAT, or I need to somehow plug your SQLFiddle example into my original query?

Comment: It doesn't need to be on a single line. I meant that the output is a group of urls as a single string. About the syntax error: it seems it trips over the double quote in the string. Can you try to escape those with a backslash? The result seems to be the same in this fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/44086) but maybe it solves the error on your config.

Comment: I just added a `select from dual` to fake some data, because I don't have your tables available. You should plug it in your own query exactly as you did. Only thing to figure out is where the syntax error is coming from (also see my remark about double quotes above).

Comment: I finally got it to work. Instead of cutting and pasting, I retyped the code. This is what it looks like: GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href=\"', GG.URL, '\" title=\"', GG.Name, '\">', GG.Name, '</a>')) AS Names

Comment: The double quotes after all. They weren't needed in the fiddle I made, although it worked with them as well. I've updated the answer to reflect this. Thanks for the feedback, and good to hear that it works.